# ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist after installing @stripe/stripe-react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I'm integrating [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) into my react native project and after running;

```
npx expo install @stripe/stripe-react-native
```

and then;

```
eas build -p -ios --auto-submit
```

I am getting the above error when submitting to Test Flight in iOS. I am aware this is an error suggesting I need to request permissions of some sort in the Info.plist file, however, I have looked through the Expo Docs [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/) to see if I am missing any configuration in my app.json file but to no avail.

So far I have just set up my stripe provider in. `App.js` as such;

```
<StripeProvider
    publishableKey={PUBLISHABLE_KEY}
    merchantIdentifier={MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER}>
 <Layout />
</StripeProvider>
```

### app.json

```
"plugins": [
      "expo-apple-authentication",
      [
        "@stripe/stripe-react-native",
        {
          "merchantIdentifier": "merchant.XXXXXXXXXX.customer--app",
          "enableGooglePay": false
        }
      ]
    ]
```

### app.json (second format)

```
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-apple-authentication",
        [
          "@stripe/stripe-react-native",
          {
            "merchantIdentifier": "merchant.XXXXXXXXXX.customer--app",
            "enableGooglePay": false
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: Did you add also these information in your app.json ?
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native#expo

Comment: Yes, I will update my question with app.json

Comment: Just mentioning it does say plugin not found under  "@stripe/stripe-react-native",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Stripe Support:

> The underlying Stripe iOS SDK, which the Stripe React Native SDK
> relies on, requires use of the device's camera for the card scanning
> feature that is present with PaymentSheet. This is why you see a
> reference to specifying “NSCameraUsageDescription” as part of your
> app's config.

Adding:

```
"infoPlist": {
  "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to scan payment cards."
},
```

under `"ios"` in `app.json` has resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
[
        "@stripe/stripe-react-native",
        {
          "merchantIdentifier": "xxx.xxxx.xxxx",
          "enableGooglePay": true
        }
],
```

to your app.json
I'm not 100 % sure, but maybe the merchant id should not have the --app?, just for kicks try creating another one in simpler form like com.company.app

Comment: I have updated my question with app.json config please take a look.

Comment: I removed the merchantIdentifier from the app.json and App.js to start with as I believe these are only for Apple Pay - it's had the same effect so I'm not sure changing the MerchantID will do anything?

Comment: quick one, is it failing to build?

Comment: No it's appears to be building, it's when it hits the App Store it seems to fail. In the terminal I get: "Your binary has been successfully uploaded to App Store Connect!"